# Process.Start Launches EXE but with error... But if i launch exe myself it runs fine

Tags: c#

the error says it errored on the line that starts with `gr.Copy`:

```
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
        Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        gr.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bmp.Size);
        bmp.Save(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) + @"\Pictures\RSB\" + System.Environment.MachineName + ".png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

Also it works in visual studio debug on the os or on a normal windows 10 os. The one it errors on is Windows Server 2019 Datacenter

Error Picture:

[Picture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWVKF.png)

Code of Process.Start():

```
                    Process process = new Process()
                    {
                        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) + @"\Desktop\RSB\RSB.exe")
                        {
                            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
                            WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) + @"\Desktop\RSB\RSB.exe")
                        }
                    };

                    process.Start();
```

Comment: Is screen locked?

Comment: Yeah im using remote desktop to connect and just found out if im not viewing the rdp it crashes if i am it works fine. Any ideas for a work around?

Comment: The process class does not set any environmental variables like PATH.  So a missing environmental variable usually is cause when exe runs and same code does not work from inside c# using process class.